# How to use column value in sql comparison condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to query a certain data based comparing value in a column. 
consider below table.

```
Order_Number    File_Name
123             100-200-123.pdf
234             200-300-234.pdf
345             500-600-556.pdf
```

Now I want to select Order_Number where Order_Number is not part of File_Name. I want to run query in Oracle DB.

I tried this.

```
select Order_Number from table_name where File_Name not like '%&&Order_Number%'
```

obviously it didn't work and gave a dialog to enter value for order_number in sql developer.

In short my query should return only 345. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `I want to select Order_Number where Order_Number is part of File_Name`. Did you mean "where Order_Number is ***not*** part of File_Name"?  I ask, because you are expecting your output to be 345.

Comment: Yes I corrected thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
select Order_Number from table_name where File_Name not like '%' || order_number || '%'
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/31666/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT Order_Number 
FROM tableA 
WHERE File_Name NOT LIKE '%' || Order_Number || '%';
```

In this you will for every line look what value is in `Order_Number`. And  you look if that value exists in `File_Name`. By using `%` before and behind it you allow other values to be before and behind it.

For example if you would use `WHERE File_Name NOT LIKE Order_Number || '%'` then you would only look at the `File_Names` that start with the `Order_Number`.